# Parse.Query returning fewer objects than the limit

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to return a list of users from my User class. I have 101 users. I get 90 users back.

I know that Parse queries cap the data at 100 objects unless specified, so I should be getting at least 100. Why am I getting fewer than 100? Where are my stray 11?

Here's my code:

```
function avAuthTime_C(){
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.limit = 1000;
query.count({
success: function(number) {
    // There are number instances of MyClass.
    console.log("Total Instances: "+number);
},

error: function(error) {
    // error is an instance of Parse.Error.
    console.log("Parse error");
    }
});
```

I have heard that Parse is being phased out. We're building an app for a long term school project, and while we'll be working on it for a few months, we'll be done (and graduated!) by the time parse closes.

Comment: Since you're new to JavaScript/Parse, you may wish to look at the tag wiki for [tag:parse.com], where it mentions that it is being phased out. Might want to learn something different :).

Comment: Thank you, I have heard that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the following [post](https://parse.com/questions/javascript-api-skip-limit-not-working), you should be able to use _limit and _skip, and it should function properly.

Example:

```
query.count({
    success: function(count) {
        var chunk = 100;
        var cycles = Math.ceil(count / chunk);

        for (i = 0; i < cycles; i++) {
            var _query = new Parse.Query("ClassName");
            _query.descending("createdAt");
            _query._limit = chunk;
            _query._skip = i * chunk;

            console.log("getting results " + _query.skip.toString() + " to " + (_query.skip + _query.limit).toString());

            _query.find({
                success: function(results) {
                    var template = $("#ClassNameTemplate").html();
                    var class_name_html = Mustache.to_html(template, {"ClassName": results});
                    $("#classNameTable").find("tbody").append(class_name_html);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log("error");
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```